# Mysql Join for 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

***I have checked former posts and none has solved my problem yet, any help would be appreciated***

MYSQL query to 3 tables (Users, Match, Interview)

Want to return the users name and interview # (if there is an interview number) for the specified Match.

But I do not want to limit the results to only users who have an interview. I tried JOIN, but cannot get it to work for 3 tables.

Here is what I have so far in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name,'----',COALESCE(i.v_code,'')) as name, u.id as id
FROM #__users as u

 JOIN #__bl_match as m ON ( (u.team_id = m.team1_id) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team2_id) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team3_id AND m.team3_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team4_id AND m.team4_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team5_id AND m.team5_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team6_id AND m.team6_id != 0) OR
     (u.team_id = m.team7_id AND m.team7_id != 0) OR
     (u.team_id = m.team8_id AND m.team8_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team9_id AND m.team9_id != 0) OR
     (u.team_id = m.team10_id AND m.team10_id != 0)) 
   AND m.id = ".$t_id."AND m.id != 0 

JOIN #__bl_interview as i ON i.u_id = u.id";

        $db->setQuery($query);
    $parti12 = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Did you try LEFT JOIN? JOIN will fetch only users who have a corresponding entity(ies) in the joining table.

Comment: Just changed it. But now it does not show the users names, just spaces in the drop down box

Comment: Try adding LEFT JOIN to #__bl_match table aswell.

Comment: Thats not it...gives me nothing but spaces now in drop down box. I am guessing that I need to switch Match and Users to Join

Comment: For the Users without Interviews, `i.v_code` will be NULL. Concatenating that with their name will return NULL. You need to handle this case so that a name appears for each User.

Comment: You should probably do some reading on [the various joins and how they work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: Also, why the GROUP BY clause? You're not aggregating anything...

Comment: I am using the results to populate my drop down box. Any idea on how to show name and i.v_code (if there is one) without NULL name?

Comment: Good point on Group by clause....removed

Comment: You could `COALESCE(i.v_code, '')` to turn a NULL code into the empty string.

Comment: Awesome, I am trying that now

Comment: Hey, submit an answer so I can give you points

Comment: @user1071915 I submitted an answer. Are the aforementioned points forthcoming? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want Users with no Interview, you'll need to use a LEFT JOIN to the interview table, but that means the interview number for that user will be NULL.

Since you're concatenating the number with the user name in your SELECT list, this results in the user's name being returned as NULL when they've got no interviews (since concatenating a string with a NULL value - or performing pretty much any other operation on a NULL value - produces a NULL result).

To avoid this, you must handle the case when `i.v_code` is NULL. The typical way to do that in MySQL is with the [COALESCE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name, '----', COALESCE(i.v_code,'')) as name, 
       u.id as id
FROM #__users as u
JOIN #__bl_match as m ON ( (u.team_id = m.team1_id) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team2_id) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team3_id AND m.team3_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team4_id AND m.team4_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team5_id AND m.team5_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team6_id AND m.team6_id != 0) OR
     (u.team_id = m.team7_id AND m.team7_id != 0) OR
     (u.team_id = m.team8_id AND m.team8_id != 0) OR 
     (u.team_id = m.team9_id AND m.team9_id != 0) OR
     (u.team_id = m.team10_id AND m.team10_id != 0)) 
   AND m.id = ".$t_id."AND m.id != 0 
LEFT JOIN #__bl_interview as i ON i.u_id = u.id"
```

Now, given the formatting you're applying to the name, you may be left with an extraneous `----` after the name with no subsequent interview code. If you'd like to avoid that, we can use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) instead of COALESCE to get a little smarter with our output, like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name, IF(i.v_code, '---- ' + i.v_code, '')) as name
```

Note what that's doing: if `i.v_code` is not NULL, the first expression in the IF evaluates to true, so the *second* expression is returned. Otherwise, the third expression (the empty string) is returned - so when `i.v_code` is NULL, you only output the user's name.